# How to return an image to the client using Nest.js framework?

Tags: image, file, return, nestjs

I am building an application, currently facing a problem  I want to return an images which is stored in my server. I want to return image to React client, then it would be rendered in my component. But I can't figure out how to return the image itself. As far as I understand, I need to return image as JSON? But can't figure out how to do it in Nest.js framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should have a service, to serve static files. You can achieve this with Nest.JS. For example, if your images are placed in a public folder, placed in the root of your project, simply you can serve it, by adding the following line to your `main.ts` file:

```js
import { join } from 'path';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use('/public', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'))); // <-
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

Then for example you have `cat.png` placed in the public folder, and you want to send this in your response, you can send something like this:

```js
{
   image: `${baseUrl}/public/cat.png`
}
```

For example for your local server, `baseURL` will be `http://localhost:3000`.
You can take a look at [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/nestjs-upload-serve-static-file/) article for more detailed explanations.

Comment: I did the same. That is in main.ts file I put the code ```app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'pictures')));``` It is storing file in dist folder instead of inside src. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: I got the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'static')' at express.static